# How to config built-in DHCP server in VirtualBox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, dns, android

I'm trying to build testbed to evaluate my program.  I don't have physical hardware (server, switch, router), so I decided to use VirtualBox to virtualize everything.  The requirements is as follows

1. 3 Servers, one of them is DNS nameserver that I modified for this testbed and I need to use it.
2. 1 Android phone, I'm using Android x86.  I wanted to use real phone but I don't know how to connect to VirtualBox network.  So, I ended up using virtualized Android.
3. All devices must be able to access Internet.  I achieved this by using NAT Network mode.
4. All devices can talk to each other.  I achieved this by using NAT Network mode.
5. All devices must use DNS nameserver that is in VirtualBox, NAT Network.

I have problem with 4., I can change nameserver of servers easily because it just Debian but I can't change Android's nameserver.  I don't even know how Android got internet access but I assume that built-in DHCP server send Android nameservers, though when I used IP tools to check nameserver, it showed 0.0.0.0 address.

So, is there anyway to change Android's nameserver to one of the server in NAT Network?

I also open for any virtualize solution that meets my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After I researched, I found workaround to meet my requirement now.  According to [VirtualBox manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch09.html#nat-adv-dns)

> For resolving network names, the DHCP server of the NAT engine offers a list of registered DNS servers of the host. If for some reason you need to hide this DNS server list and use the host's resolver settings, thereby forcing the VirtualBox NAT engine to intercept DNS requests and forward them to host's resolver, use the following command:

Because NAT engine offers a list of registered DNS servers of the host, so I'm able to set host's DNS nameserver to DNS nameserver in VirtualBox.  The process is as follows:

1. Set port forwarding of NAT Network, host IP `127.0.0.1` and host port `53` UDP to IP of nameserver in VirtualBox and port 53.
2. Changed nameserver setting of host to 127.0.0.1.

Host DNS resolving still works, as well as all servers in VirtualBox.